# check if row exists with specific value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables `task` and `taskattributes`. There is a linking between 2 tables with `taskid`. Each `taskid` has multiple attributes represented by `key,value`.
I would like to find out if specific key exists for the task

[image]

[image]

For e.g. here if I want to check all the tasks which do not have key 'A'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution uses aggregation:

```
SELECT
    t.taskid,
    t.name
FROM task t
INNER JOIN taskattributes ta
    ON t.taskid = ta.taskid
GROUP BY
    t.taskid,
    t.name
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN "key" = 'A' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

If you are using Postgres 9.4 or later, you may use `FILTER` in the `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "key" = 'A') = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

use `correlated subquery` with `not exists`

```
select a.taskid, b.key, b.value
from task a inner join taskattributes b on a.taskid=b.taskid
where not exist 
     (select 1 from taskattributes c on c.taskid=b.taskid and key='A')
```

Comment: . . The only reason that I will not upvote this correct answer is because of the use of arbitrary letters for table aliases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it would be great if you explain why that is a problem, it would be easy for me to learn then

Comment: . . Abbreviations for table names facilitate reading the query.  They are also stable if you take a query and modify the `from` clause.  Arbitrary letters are quite hard to follow, because the reader has to continually refer to the `from` clause to figure out where the columns come from.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your point is very valid, and moving forward I'll make an effort to keep in mind your suggestion for coding style.

Answer (score 1):

With `not exists`:

```
select *
from task t
where not exists (
  select 1 from taskattributes
  where taskid = t.taskid and key = 'A'
)
```